# How to add unordered list bullets

Tags: jquery, html, css, list

I am hosting a website in Weebly. Using a javascript I display list of items from an RSS feed in an unordered list. The structure is like this (after the javascript loaded).

```
<div class="rss-box">
 <ul class="rss-items">
  <li class="rss-item">....</li>
  .....
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Weebly doesn't support lists that are loaded using javascript. So, it does not show the bullet. Can I add bullets using jQuery after the page is loaded (using the class)?
Someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
ul {
    list-style: square outside;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$(".rss-items").css("list-style-type", "bullet");
```

Comment: Actually the javascript I use loads all the list items in unordered list with the class "rss-items". Because of the problem with template the page does not show the bullet (that means list-style: none). So, what I am asking is, after the page is fully loaded, how to change the list style for the class "rss-items" using jQuery? (I tried css in the style sheet. Does not work.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .css() method and adding a list-style-type property?